# My Numpy array has a list in it but I can't use it in Keras

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to train an LSTM but my input data contains integers and one-hot vectors which cuases a

```py
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

A row of my data frame looks like this:

```py
      date     size                                              state                                      type
408      1    32000  [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ...  [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

I converted this into a Numpy array and split it into train and test sets by following [this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/). Now I have 4 Numpy arrays of shape:

```py
print(trainX.shape, trainY.shape, testX.shape, testY.shape)
(1206, 1, 4) (1206, 4) (518, 1, 4) (518, 4)
```

Here is the code for the Keras model I'm using (based on the same tutorial mentioned above):

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(50, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(4))
model.compile(loss='mae', optimizer='adam')
# fit network
history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=50, batch_size=72, validation_data=(testX, testY), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
```

The stack trace is:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "LSTM.py", line 83, in <module>
    lstm_model(super_data.values)
  File "LSTM.py", line 71, in lstm_model
    history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=50, batch_size=72, validation_data=(testX, testY), verbose=2, shuffle=False)
  File "/home/marcus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1239, in fit
    validation_freq=validation_freq)
  File "/home/marcus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 196, in fit_loop
    outs = fit_function(ins_batch)
  File "/home/marcus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py", line 3277, in __call__
    dtype=tensor_type.as_numpy_dtype))
  File "/home/marcus/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py", line 85, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you try to remove `input_shape` from the `lstm` layer?

Comment: @Ghanem I'm still getting the same error after that.